# C++ Map throws vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I am trying to create a class which stores its instances in a map like so:

```
class Apple {
    public: 
        static Apple* getApple(const std::string &name) {
             auto it = allApples.find(name);

             if (it == allApples.end()) // if this apple doesnt exist, make a new one
                 return new Apple(name); 
             else // if the apple exists, return its pointer
                 return it->second;
        }
    private:
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*> allApples =                
            std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*>();

        Apple(const std::string &name) {
            // create an apple
            allApples.insert({ name, this });
        }
}
```

Now, I made classes which store static Apples like so:

```
class Orange {
     static Apple *myOrangeApple;
}

myOrangeApple = Apple::getApple("orange");
```

When I run the program, it crashes on the first line of the getApple() method with a vector subscript out of range error. I have tried looking around but I can't really find any solution which deals with maps and this out of range error. My best guess from some of the research I did is that it is something about the static order initialization, but I really am not too sure.

Comment: The 1st line you meant `auto it = allApples.find(name);`? I don't see anything relevant with `std::vector` or subscript operator.

Comment: @songyuanyao, Yes that line is the one that throws the debug assertion / exception (in release build). I don't see anything related to a vector either which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: Can you give us enough code so that we can compile it and replicate the problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, this is really the entirety of it... I don't access the `allApples` map ever besides that one function and constructor

Comment: Then it should be no problem to write a `main` function and confirm that it replicates the problem. Please do that.

Comment: @George I have actually. I tried put a breakpoint at the line which throws the exception and it shows that the map is properly initialized and everything. I also added a line to print the size of the map right before the exception and it prints out zero, as it should.

Comment: Well then update your question to include that code! If we can replicate the problem, we can debug it. If we can't, we can't. (And please 100% confirm that the exact code you paste does in fact replicate the problem!)

Comment: @George That it equals `allApples.end()`. That's what should happen if the element isn't found, right?

Comment: When you hit the breakpoint, had `main` already been invoked or were you initializing a `static` object?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When I backtrace at the exception, its initializing the `myOrangeApple` static object, so no, main has not yet been invoked.

Comment: @ThomasPaine That was the piece of information we needed that you hid from us. See my answer. (With that clue, the answer is obvious. And without that, you could not replicate the problem. Doing what I asked would have allowed you to solve the problem yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function-scope static object.

```
...
private:
   std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*>& allApples() {
      static std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*> apples;
      return apples;
   }
```

This is one of standard ways to fight the static initialization order fiasco. It works because a block-scope static object is guaranteed to be initialised when the block is executed for the first time.

This method will not work if there are mutual dependencies between objects managed this way.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but as an answer, it would be *much* better if you explained *why* this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

First thing your getApple method should be static and you should initialize the class member (static member) outside the class. Try this -

```
class Apple {
    public: 
        static Apple* getApple(const std::string &name) {
             auto it = allApples.find(name);

             if (it == allApples.end()) // if this apple doesnt exist, make a new one
                 return new Apple(name); 
             else // if the apple exists, return its pointer
                 return it->second;
        }
    private:
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*> allApples; 

        Apple(const std::string &name) {
            // create an apple
            allApples.insert({ name, this });
        }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*> Apple::allApples = std::unordered_map<std::string, Apple*>();

class Orange {
     static Apple *myOrangeApple;
};

Apple * Orange::myOrangeApple=Apple::getApple("orange");
```

Comment: I have my code like that, I should probably change it on here, I just didn't think it was that relevant to the question.

Comment: @ThomasPaine Without enough code to replicate the problem, there's no way anyone can tell what's relevant or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `allApples` before it's been initialized. Until you enter `main`, there's no guarantee that `allApples` has been constructed, so accessing it is a definite no-no.

Having classes that add themselves to containers is a bad idea, but doing it in a global object is truly awful. Don't do that.

Comment: But when I print out the size of `allApples` right before the breakpoint, it gives me zero, which means that `allApples` is initialized, correct? If `allApples` wasn't initialized, wouldn't it be undefined behavior then?

Comment: @ThomasPaine That is another bug in your code. You must not call `size` until `allApples` is assured to be initialized as that is UB. You happen to get zero, which misleads you. That's why you shouldn't do it!

Comment: This is why you should do as little as possible in constructors and destructors -- it's very hard to control the context in which they execute. Having this much code all called from the constructor of a global static is nuts. How can you maintain this code without putting big warnings all over it saying "DO NOT DO ANYTHING NOT LEGAL TO DO BEFORE MAIN" and propagate that through all called functions? Crazy.

Comment: What should I do instead in this situation then? Building the apple is expensive (its a file import and process), so I don't want to be building them everytime I need to access one.

Comment: You can use a factory class that manages the apples.